# Neo4j streams, fabric integration not working. Log reports "The `USE GRAPH` clause is not available in this implementation of Cypher"

Tags: neo4j

integrating my streams topics into fabric functionality is not working.
Attempting to sink my first topic into a named graph produced the message below.
I did follow the instructions provided by links to no avail.

Am I missing someting?

**The Neo4j log Error:**

ErrorData(originalTopic=twoPoly, timestamp=1620757269838, partition=0, offset=1481, exception=org.neo4j.graphdb.QueryExecutionException: The `USE GRAPH` clause is not available in this implementation of Cypher due to lack of support for USE graph selector. (line 1, column 29 (offset: 28))
"UNWIND $events AS event use integerpolys MERGE (i:IndexedBy {N:event.NN,RowCounter:event.flatFileRowCounterr,MaxN:event.nMaxx,Dimension:"2"} ) MERGE (t:TwoSeqFactor {twoSeq:event.tSeqDB} ) MERGE (v:VertexNode {Vertex:event.vertexDBVertex,Scalar:event.vertexScalarDB,Degree:event.vertexDegreeDB} ) MERGE (e:Evaluate {Value:event.targetEvaluate}) MERGE  (i)-[ee:TwoFactor]->(t) MERGE (i) -[:IndexedByEvaluate]->(e) MERGE  (i)-[:VertexIndexedBy]->(v)"
^, key=null, value={"NN":"7","nMaxx":"8","vertexDBVertex":"1 -8 1 0 0","bTermDB":"1","flatFileRowCounterr":"6","targetEvaluate":"128","vertexDB":"1 -8 1 0 0","vertexScalarDB":"-8","tSeqDB":"32","vertexDegreeDB":"1"}, executingClass=class streams.kafka.KafkaAutoCommitEventConsumer)

**Neo4j version** 4.1.0

**Relevant neo4j.conf**:

```
fabric.database.name=differences

streams.source.enabled=false

kafka.max.poll.records=1000

kafka.zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

streams.procedures.enabled=<true/false, default=true>

streams.sink.enabled=true

streams.sink.topic.cypher.twoPoly=use integerpolys \
MERGE (i:IndexedBy {N:event.NN,RowCounter:event.RowCounterr,MaxN:event.nMaxx,Dimension:"2"} ) \
MERGE (t:TwoSeqFactor {twoSeq:event.tSeqDB} ) \
MERGE (v:VertexNode        {Vertex:event.vertexDBVertex,Scalar:event.vertexScalarDB,Degree:event.vertexDegreeDB} ) \
MERGE (e:Evaluate {Value:event.targetEvaluate}) \
MERGE  (i)-[ee:TwoFactor]->(t) \
MERGE (i) -[:IndexedByEvaluate]->(e) \
MERGE  (i)-[:VertexIndexedBy]->(v)
```

**Available databases**
Databases available for the current user.
Click on one to start using it:

:use createbymu

:use differencegraph

:use fabric

:use integerpolys

:use neo4j

:use skipmu

:use system

Reference solution:

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12395

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/fabric/configuration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `USE` clause is currently not supported in this setting (only when connected using a neo4j driver).

Remove the `use integerpolys` from the query and instead configure the streams plugin with the target database directly, according to https://neo4j.com/labs/kafka/4.0/consumer/#_multi_database_support

```
streams.sink.enabled.to.integerpolys=true

streams.sink.topic.cypher.twoPoly.to.integerpolys=\
MERGE (i:IndexedBy {N:event.NN,RowCounter:event.RowCounterr,MaxN:event.nMaxx,Dimension:"2"} ) \
MERGE (t:TwoSeqFactor {twoSeq:event.tSeqDB} ) \
MERGE (v:VertexNode        {Vertex:event.vertexDBVertex,Scalar:event.vertexScalarDB,Degree:event.vertexDegreeDB} ) \
MERGE (e:Evaluate {Value:event.targetEvaluate}) \
MERGE  (i)-[ee:TwoFactor]->(t) \
MERGE (i) -[:IndexedByEvaluate]->(e) \
MERGE  (i)-[:VertexIndexedBy]->(v)
```